# Generating all permutations of pairs excluding permutations of individual elements

Tags: c, algorithm, permutation, combinatorics

I would like to generate all permutations of the ordered pairs (a, b) where a != b, and a, b are elements of set S (let's say S := {1..k}), but excluding permutations of the individual elements of S.

For example, setting k = 2, the possible ordered pairs are (1, 2), (2, 1) giving 2 possible sequences:

- (1, 2), (2, 1)
- (2, 1), (1, 2)

but which are actually duplicates under the permutation mapping of {1->2, 2->1}.

For k = 3, there would be 6 possible ordered pairs, giving 6! sequences (including duplicates). But with 3! = k possible permutations, the desired number of unique sequences is 5!, and is easily generated by only taking sequences that begin with the pair (1, 2).

In the general case, there would be k*(k-1) pairs, giving [k * (k-1)]! sequences (including duplicates), and there would be k! permutations, so I should end up with [k * (k-1)]! / k! sequences.

I only intend to use small values of k, but am wondering if there are any good ways of generating these sequences. I'm fairly certain this is a specific case of filtering out unique sequences [allowing duplicate elements] subject to permutations of the possible elements in those sequences, but maybe there's something particular about what I'm looking for that is easier than the brute-force approach of generating all possible sequences and then filtering.

Comment: @JKB From my understanding of the problem, he has tried creating all permutations and discarding redundancies. But this requires quite an overhead - creating records you won't need eventually. He is looking for a way to calculate the desired result directly without this overhead.

Comment: @amit you are right, OP want just remove overhead but if he should give some of his approach towards remove overhead then it would be batter.So we can think on him approach if he go on right approach then we will give our hand to achieve his approach. And sorry for my immediate unwanted response towards OP.next time i will keep that in my mind.also have removed my prev comment.thanks amit again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can extend your approach of only generating sequences that start with (1,2) to only generate sequences that if you consider each digit in turn then either:

1. the digit matches a previous digit
2. the digit is the next unseen digit

So a sequence like (1,2)(2,1) and (1,2)(3,4) would be allowed, but not (1,2)(4,5) because the 4 violates the rules (3 is the next unseen digit at this stage).

Given this you can then generate all the combinations recursively by choosing each pair in turn, where each pair must be both a new pair, and satisfy the rules.

e.g. for k=3

```
(1,2) Only option for level 1
(1,2) can be followed by (2,1) or (1,3) or (2,3) or (3,1) or (3,2)
(1,2)(2,1) can be followed by (3,1) or (3,2) or (1,3) or (2,3)
(1,2)(2,1)(3,1) can be followed by...
```

Comment: This is the way to do it. We can use [McKay's framework](http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/papers/orderly.pdf) to prove so. This algorithm uses the lexicographic minimum as its canonical labeling, and the implicit algorithm for constructing this labeling is simple: map the jth distinct occurring element to j. Since the labeling algorithm is online, the lower/upper object stuff is trivial.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at backtraking algorithm:

http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/course/cis680/cis680Ch19.html

Generating permutations is an NPC problem so all solutions will have an exponential complexity.

Comment: (1) [NP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_(complexity)) Problems are also problems that are solveable polynomially. You probably mean [NP Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete). (2) This is not NP Complete Problem, since the output size is exponential, so even if P=NP, there is no polynomial solution to this problem.

Comment: Also, the OP has already described a way to do it with permutations, but want to avoid the overhead of generating too many permutations and discarding one of them.

Comment: Enumeration algorithms conventionally are judged by how long they take to produce each piece of output. For Peter's algorithm, this time is bounded by a polynomial in k.